# IMobileServiceTable.ReadAsync(string query) syntax

Tags: azure

Can anyone tell me where to find the syntax for the query string parameter for Windows Azure's `IMobileServiceTable.ReadAsync(string query)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an ODATA query. Search google for "ODATA QUERY" for details. It's less work to use a Where method on the table and let LINQ construct the ODATA query internally.